# Access individual JSON elements in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json, dom

I have parsed a JSON from an external source to the HTML page and I am passing it with a div tag and an ID for div tag say "x".

```html
<div id = "x">
[{"root":"root1","group":"L1","subgroup":"L1.1","Dollar.Value":1000,"Color.Name":"WHITE","Transparency":0.5763},{"root":"root2","group":"L1","subgroup":"L1.2","Dollar.Value":4000,"Color.Name":"RED","Transparency":0.1836}]
</div>
```

I need to access each element individually now for my further requirement. 
one example is root(2) needs to return root2 
one other example is Dollar.Value(2) needs to return 4000

Any leads on how to achieve the same will be much appreciated.

Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parse div string need:

```
var json_text=$('#x').html();     //read div content
var json=$.parseJSON(json_text);  //parse content to JSON
```

for jet Dollar.Value(2)

```
   json[1]['Dollar.Value']   //not json[1].Dollar.Value
```

if need read all json element:

```js
var json_text=$('#x').html();
var json=$.parseJSON(json_text);
for(var key in json){
 var element=json[key];
 for(var el in element){
        console.log(el+' => '+element[el]);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id = "x">
[{"root":"root1","group":"L1","subgroup":"L1.1","Dollar.Value":1000,"Color.Name":"WHITE","Transparency":0.5763},{"root":"root2","group":"L1","subgroup":"L1.2","Dollar.Value":4000,"Color.Name":"RED","Transparency":0.1836}]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the JSON into a JS object and assign the value to an appropriate element

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name );
```

The above code will alert with 'John'

You can set any element value in jquery using Jquery as

```
$("#ID3).val(obj.name);
```

Comment: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(document.getElementById("x").innerHTML);
alert(obj);
I tried to do something like this, but it alerts "Null"

Comment: alert(obj[1]['Dollar.Value']);

Answer (score 0):

You can print out by looping through the json array.

```
//Assign json result to a variable
const data = jQuery.parseJSON("YOUR JSON HERE")

//Then use each function to loop 
$.each(data, function(key, item){
 //Now you have access to all the items inside that array :-
 alert(item.root)
 //Print it out in html
 $(".root").val(item.root);
})
```

html markup

```
<div class="x">
  <div class="root">
   //Root value comes here
  </div>
</div>
```